# Need help figuring out SystemD timer with wake up from Suspend

Tags: bash, python, suspend, systemd

I have a systemd service file and timer file that wakeup laptop and should run a python script. Then when that's done, run a bash script that puts it back into suspend. It currently wakes up the laptop, then a little while later suspends. Not sure why it's giving the error it does. Works fine from the commandline when the python script is run manually. The status for both timer and service included.

environment:

```
WXFORECAST_PUSHOVER_APP_KEY=randomAPPKey
WXFORECAST_COORDINATES=31.02,-90.56
PUSHOVER_DEVICE=weather
PUSHOVER_USER_KEY=randomGroupKey
```

status service

```
● wxforecast.service - Send Weather Update
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wxforecast.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-29 07:00:24 CDT; 3h 56min ago
  Process: 31417 ExecStopPost=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/sus.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31287 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/william/CODE/wxforecast/wxforecast.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31287 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 29 07:00:24 william python3[31287]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
May 29 07:00:24 william python3[31287]:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
May 29 07:00:24 william python3[31287]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
May 29 07:00:24 william python3[31287]:     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
May 29 07:00:24 william python3[31287]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.weather.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /points/35.0
May 29 07:00:24 william systemd[1]: wxforecast.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 29 07:00:24 william sudo[31424]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl suspend
May 29 07:00:24 william sudo[31424]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 29 07:00:24 william sudo[31424]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 29 07:00:24 william systemd[1]: wxforecast.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

status timer

```
● wxforecast.timer - Send Weather Update
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wxforecast.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2020-05-24 18:33:02 CDT; 4 days ago
  Trigger: Sat 2020-05-30 07:00:00 CDT; 20h left
```

`sus.sh`

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/systemctl suspend
```

`wxforecast.py`

```
## https://github.com/stacybrock/wxforecast

import os
import nwswx
import requests


(LAT, LON) = [c.strip() for c in os.getenv('WXFORECAST_COORDINATES',
                                           '39.0693,-94.6716').split(',')]

def main():
    nws = nwswx.WxAPI('[wxforecast] brock@oregonstate.edu')
    result = nws.point_forecast(LAT, LON, return_format=nwswx.formats.JSONLD)
    forecast = result['periods'][0]

    # create pushover notification
    title = f"{forecast['shortForecast']}"
    msg = f"""{forecast['detailedForecast']}
    Temp: {forecast['temperature']}°{forecast['temperatureUnit']}
    Wind: {forecast['windSpeed']} {forecast['windDirection']}
    Details: https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lon={LON}&lat={LAT}
    """
    r = requests.post('https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json', data = {
        'token': os.environ['WXFORECAST_PUSHOVER_APP_KEY'],
        'user': os.environ['PUSHOVER_USER_KEY'],
        'message': msg,
        'title': title,
        'device': os.environ['PUSHOVER_DEVICE']
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`wxforecast.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Send Weather Update
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="WXFORECAST_PUSHOVER_APP_KEY=RandomAppKEY"
Environment="WXFORECAST_COORDINATES=31.02,-90.56"
Environment="PUSHOVER_DEVICE=weather"
Environment="PUSHOVER_USER_KEY=randomUserGroupKey"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/william/CODE/wxforecast/wxforecast.py
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/sus.sh
StandardError=journal
```

`wxforecast.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Send Weather Update

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 07:00:00
Persistent=true
WakeSystem=true
Unit=wxforecast.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Additional info: Xubuntu 18.04 Desktop. All the files involved are in the gist as separate files.

Parsa Mousavi - possibly because of WIFI. Maybe I need to move the python line to a shell script and add a sleep command before it runs the python script. I'll give that a try and report back tomorrow morning. That really seems like the only reason as I haven't/won't ever get near the 7500 API requests for the free account on any given month as this should only run once daily. Lately I've been really fatigued after having my right leg amputated below the knee. So obvious things haven't seemed as obvious as they should. :(

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: It looks like the timer and service are working fine. Your script is having problems, but you have given only partial output.

Comment: Return code of your service initialization is 1 . So somewhere in your script there's an error which returns 1 ( which is "operation not permitted" in some cases). You can debug-by-print your code and see the logs to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Oh , when I paid more attention to your service status , I found out that it had exited with the following error : "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.weather.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /points/35.0" . You have some kind of connectivity problem.

Comment: I think everything is OK with your systemd service except the "After=network-online.target" part . As stated [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) it "Usually it indicates a configured, routable IP address of some kind" , so it doesn't necessarily mean that you can access your target "api.pushover.net" . Do you use any VPNs? VPNs might have some delay before actually getting up to work.So even after some retries , your script still cannot send the info to the target.

Comment: Please post an answer below your question so others know the solution. Also accept your answer two days after date of question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for was to ping google until it responded. Changed out the sleep I added with this below(found on Serverfault)(could probably work with vanilla ping, but this is the one I choose):

```
sudo apt-get install fping
```

```
HOSTNAMES=google.com
while ! fping -q $HOSTNAMES ; do :; done
```

Now it pings for google until google responds then runs whatever the next command is in the shell script.

Thanks everyone for the push in the right direction.